# Spring Thymealef Ajax update fragmenet

Tags: ajax, spring-mvc, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I'm using spring boot MVC, and have a part that I make an ajax request to update a collection of products for merchandise shipment, but when I post it is displaying json on the screen instead of updating the fragment:

```
        <th:block th:if="${expedicao.tipoRegistro eq 'A' or expedicao.tipoRegistro eq 'X'}">
        <form action="#" th:action="@{/expedicao/buscaprod}" method="post"
            name="formBusca">
            <input type="hidden" th:name="${_csrf.parameterName}"
                th:value="${_csrf.token}" /> <label th:text="Ean13">Ean13</label>
            <input type="radio" name="tipoCod" id="tipoCod" value="ean13" /> <label
                th:text="Dun14">Dun14</label> <input type="radio" name="tipoCod"
                id="tipoCod" value="dun14" /> <input type="text"
                name="FieldCodigo" class="form-control" placeholder="Codigo Barras"
                id="FieldCodigo" value="" autofocus="autofocus" required="required" />
            <input type="hidden" name="id_expedicao" id="id_expedicao"
                th:value="${expedicao.id}" />
            <button type="submit" value="Buscar">Buscar</button>
        </form>
    </th:block>

    <div th:fragment="info-success" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" th:remove="tag">
        <div class="modal-body row" id="coleta">
            <div th:replace="expedicao/coleta::coleta"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

this is my ajax

```
<th:block layout:fragment="scripts">
<script th:inline="javascript">
    /*<![CDATA[*/
    $(function() {
        $.ajaxSetup({
            headers : {
                'X-CSRF-Token' : $('meta[name=_token]').attr('content')
            }
        });
        $('form#formBusca').submit(
                function(e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    $.ajax({

                        type : "POST",
                        contentType : "application/json",
                        url : 'expedicao/buscaprod',
                        data : $('form#formBusca').serialize(),
                        dataType : 'json',
                        success : function(result) {
                            if(result.status == "Done"){
                                carregarColeta(result.data.id);
                        if (result.data.situacao == 'B'
                                    || result.data.situacao == 'C') {
                                $('form#formBusca').remove();
                            }
                        },
                        error : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                            console.log(JSON.stringify(jqXHR));
                            console.log("AJAX error:" + textStatus + ' : '
                                    + errorThrown);
                        }
                    });
                    $('input[name=FieldCodigo]').val('');
                });
    });
    function carregarColeta(idexpedicao) {
        $.ajax({
            method : 'POST',
            url : 'expedicao/detalhe',
            data : {
                'id_expedicao' : idexpedicao
            },
            success : function(retorno) {
                $('#coleta').empty().html(retorno);
            },
            error : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log(JSON.stringify(jqXHR));
                console.log("AJAX error:" + textStatus + ' : '
                        + errorThrown);
            }
        });
    }
```

when a execute the post method it go to my controller execute the logic and return the json of the object updated, and instead of update the fragment calling the JS function carregaExpedicao.. its dislpay the json on the screen, and change the url

this is my controller

```
@Controller
```

public class ExpedicaoController {

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/expedicao/buscaprod", method = RequestMethod.POST) 
@ResponseBody
public Response updateProdutoColetado(
        @RequestParam(name = "id_expedicao") String id_expedicao,
        @RequestParam(name = "FieldCodigo") String FieldCodigo,
        Model model, HttpSession session) {
            //Minhas regras

        model.addAttribute("expedicao", expedAndamento);
    return new Response("Done", expedAndamento);
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/expedicao/detalhe")
public String detalhe(@RequestParam(name = "id_expedicao") String id_expedicao, Model model, HttpSession session) {
    model.addAttribute("expedicao", expedAndamento);
    return "expedicao/coleta";
}

}
```

Fixed:
error 1 => id on the form
error 2 => missing csrf param on ajax

Comment: after this line of code "if(result.status == "Done"){" could you have this statement console.log("after done"); and let me know if this statement is printed, thanks

Comment: Hy thanks for the help.. i tested and i never get the result.. the i look closer the problem was in the form..  a used the attribute "name" insted ou if and on JS a search for id

now i'm gettin a diferent problem
on java console i get the error
2018-02-28 13:20:08.724  INFO 18160 --- [io-8080-exec-10] c.t.D.h.LoggingAccessDeniedHandler       : User 'BETO' attempted to access the protected URL: /expedicao/buscaprod

and JS console i get
{"readyState":4,"responseText":"<!DOCTYPE html>\r\n<html>\r\n<head>\r\n    <title>Access Denied</title>